# React Problem: "Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Tags: reactjs, devextreme

I encountered this problem when writing a .jsx file using devextreme-react.

I am using React to develop web, and I have an Array called "ServerStatusList" containing "server-status" objects in the following form:

{
  server: String,
  online: Number, 
  offline: Number, 
  vendor: String
}.

Now, I want to use each "server-status" object to generate a "Circular Gauge" chart, using the Devextreme-react library. So what I did was first creating an array react element using the "map" function, mapping each 'server-status' in the 'serverStatusList' to a CircularGauge element.

My intended effect is that a list of gauges appear on my web page.

```
const gaugeItems = vendorStatusList.map((i, index) => (
  <CircularGauge
     value={i.online}
     subvalues={[i.online]}
  >
  </CircularGauge>
));
```

Then in my JSX file, in the render9() {} function, I wrote this:

```
return(
  <Paper>
   {gaugeItems}
  </Paper> 
);
```

However, I got the error message:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {server, online, offline, vendor}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Does anyone know what the error means? I think my "gaugeItems" in between the  tag is an array, as I checked it with "typeof". I am guessing that this method does not work in cases when the things in the list are objects, but only in the cases when the things in the list are primitive-typed items. Does anyone know what happens?

Comment: The implementation seems to be correct in the current shape, can you create a small implementation in https://codesandbox.io/ for more debugging

Comment: I think that .map may need a return statement after the => the arrow operator only works with simple code, if it gets too complex, you need to return it. I actually think that your outer brackets on the RHS may be causing it.

Comment: @MarkRabjohn `()` are parentheses, correctly used for a multi-line expression. return is needed inside `{}` but a missing return here would produce an array of undefined and not cause this problem anyway

Comment: Could you show us how "vendorStatusList" looks like. Could be a problem with its properties. The rest of the code looks correct

Comment: the problem is outside of the code listed here. FTR `typeof []` is "object" in JavaScript, so not sure what you were trying to check - in any case, if `vendorStatusList` wasn't an Array, then `vendorStatusList.map(...)` would produce a TypeError and if it didn't, that means that `gaugeItems` is also an Array (assuming you are not using custom objects with a non-native map method). please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example